# Filtering a column with an empty array in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame which contains a lot of repeated values. An aggregated, distinct count of it looks like below

```
> df.groupby('fruits').count().sort(F.desc('count')).show()


| fruits        | count       |
| -----------   | ----------- |
| [Apples]      | 123         |
| []            | 344         |
| [Apples, plum]| 444         |
```

My goal is to filter all rows where the value is either `[Apples]` or `[]`.

Suprisingly, the following works for an non-empty array but for empty it doesn't

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as T

is_apples = F.udf(lambda arr: arr == ['Apples'], T.BooleanType())
df.filter(is_apples(df.fruits).count() # WORKS! shows 123 correctly.

is_empty = F.udf(lambda arr: arr == [], T.BooleanType())
df.filter(is_empty(df.fruits).count() # Doesn't work! Should show 344 but shows zero.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It might be an array containing an empty string:

```
is_empty = F.udf(lambda arr: arr == [''], T.BooleanType())
```

Or it might be an array of null:

```
is_empty = F.udf(lambda arr: arr == [None], T.BooleanType())
```

To check them all at once you can use:

```
is_empty = F.udf(lambda arr: arr in [[], [''], [None]], T.BooleanType())
```

But actually you don't need a UDF for this, e.g. you can do:

```
df.filter("fruits = array() or fruits = array('') or fruits = array(null)")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by checking the length if the array.

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

is_empty = F.udf(lambda arr: len(arr) == 0, T.BooleanType())
df.filter(is_empty(df.fruits).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use UDF, you can use F.size to get the size of the array.

To filter empty array:

```
df.filter(F.size(df.fruits) == 0)
```

To filter non-empty array:

```
df.filter(F.size(df.fruits) != 0)
```